# Dirtcheap laptop for file management

Tags: laptop, cheap

I got a Thinkpad T480 for uni, but I ended up using it only for code compiling, which I can do on my Android tbh; writing emails, which I also can do on my phone; organizing files on my NTFS drive, which the phone can't do. So I plan on selling the T480 and getting a laptop that costs around 100$ just for managing files.

I would really like it to be less than 3kg, have at least 720p screen, external battery, USB 3 optional. If the CPU can run Chrome without going over 30% usage, I'm good. RAM upgradeable to 8 would be nice.

I have my eyes on the T440 for the moment, but if you have a better recommendation, please do tell.

Comment: The T440 isn't around $100 though